# Uso de "pichichi" en Hispanoamérica

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, diferencias-regionales, hispanoamérica, deportes

La palabra del día de hoy en la [web de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es) es:

> **[pichichi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SumZwY2)**
>
> `De Pichichi, apodo de R. Moreno Aranzadi, 1892-1922, futbolista del Athletic Club, famoso por haber sido el primero en marcar un gol en el estadio bilbaíno de San Mamés.`
>
> 1. m. En el fútbol, jugador que marca más goles durante la liga española y, por ext., goleador.
> 2. m. En el fútbol, distinción honorífica que se concede al **pichichi**.

Veo que la definición pone "en la liga española". Así que pregunto: ¿se usa el término *pichichi* en otras ligas de fútbol en Hispanoamérica? Si no es así, ¿se usa allí algún otro término para el jugador que marca más goles durante la liga?

Comment: La wikipedia no tiene información exhaustiva al respecto, pero de entre la que hay no encuentro ninguna referencia. Véase [Category:Lists of association football league top scorers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_association_football_league_top_scorers).

Comment: Por lo visto en Mexico *pichichi* es otra cosa. pichichi → [pichiche](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pichiche)

Comment: @blonfu exacto, vi esa definición en el _Diccionario de Americanismos_, pero no me pareció relevante para la pregunta.

Comment: Es que la wikipedia habla de este pato, así como de un plato que en México se denominan así: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pichichi_(desambiguaci%C3%B3n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El término se usa en el sentido que da el DLE sin incluir la extensión y solo en algunos medios deportivos. Guardando las proporciones, es similar al uso del término *capocannoniere* (exclusivo para Italia). No se habla del pichichi de la Copa Libertadores o de la Copa del mundo (me parece haber leído en ciertas webs españolas hablar del pichichi de Europa). Se habla simplemente de goleador en las ligas locales o de un torneo de fútbol.